# Change Stata code to R

Tags: r, stata, logistic-regression

I need to fix a logistic regression model using R. Here is Stata code:

```
melogit num, binomial(varsum)
```

I try a code in R but the results are different. This is my code in R.

```
summary(glm(cbind(num,nonum) ~ -1 + varsum, family = binomial("logit")))
```

Output from Stata

```
Logistic regression                             Number of obs     =         18
Binomial variable:         vsum

                                                Wald chi2(0)      =          .
Log likelihood = -26.242541                     Prob > chi2       =          .
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         num |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       _cons |  -1.170071   .2202982    -5.31   0.000    -1.601848   -.7382947
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

From R

```
Call:
glm(formula = cbind(num, nonum) ~ vsum - 1, family = binomial("logit"))

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-13.5137   -3.9972   -0.7592    2.8821   10.7677  

Coefficients:
   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
vsum -0.82854    0.03839  -21.58   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 3198.67  on 18  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  673.14  on 17  degrees of freedom
AIC: 704.92

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 7
```

These are data:

```
num = c(0,1,2,0,5,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,3,6,0,0,1,4) 

nonum = c(116,43,206,130,146,97,173,73,96,112,66,70,185,181,118,252,344,60) 

varsum = c(3,4,11,7,11,5,4,3,20,3,7,1,8,17,0,1,4,5)
```

Comment: *"but the results are different"* How are they different? Please share your data and also include the Stata and R outputs.

Comment: These are data
num = c(0,1,2,0,5,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,3,6,0,0,1,4)
nonum = c(116,43,206,130,146,97,173,73,96,112,66,70,185,181,118,252,344,60)
varsum = c(3,4,11,7,11,5,4,3,20,3,7,1,8,17,0,1,4,5)

Comment: Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50877945/edit) button to revise your post; don't put code or critical details in comments. That makes it very difficult to read. Still missing the Stata and R outputs...

Comment: ok I put those in the post.

Answer (score 2):

You're fitting two different models.

First off, [`melogit`](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/memelogit.pdf) defines a multi-level mixed-effects logistic regression model, whereas `glm(..., family = binomial("logit"))` fits a simple logistic regression model.

I'm not familiar with Stata, but a quick search suggest that an equivalent logistic regression model with proportion data can be estimated with `glm` in combination with the `link(logit) family(binomial) robust` options.

Comment: That is my question how to do multi-level mixed-effects logistic regression in R.

Comment: @user9484716 **That's not clear at all from your question!** You don't mention mixed-effect models anywhere in your main post. That makes it a very different question. You can implement mixed-effect models in R using e.g. the R package `lme4`. There exist many publicly available `lme4` tutorials, I suggest spending some time researching. SO is not a code writing service; the community is happy to help *after* you've shown a decent amount of effort.